# Reliable way to deploy SW via GPO Software Installation (Active Directory), including laptops on Wi-Fi

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, active-directory, group-policy, windows-installer

Have you ever wondered how to install software onto Windows machines in a reliable way in Active Directory via native GPO? (I mean this: `Group Policy Management -> Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Software Settings -> Software Installation`)

More specifically, looking for a reliable way for **laptops on Wi-Fi - most of them don't perform software installations**. I noticed that they actually got network configured (standard DHCP via WiFi) several seconds **after the login screen**, which is obviously wrong, since Software Installation is performed before the login screen, when you've got *synchronous Group policy processing* enabled - and we've had it enabled for several years, because it had resolved many issues regarding automatic software deployment. There are several steps needed to force GPO processing not until network is available - read the answer below...

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question has been "how to install software in a reliable way in Active Directory via native GPO" and I have answered the question below, because I find it both very useful and, unfortunately, hard to achieve...

Comment: It sounds more like you've posted a commentary, and then an answer. Making the question more clearly and completely a question will stop these close votes and make this a better fit. There's nothing wrong with answering your own question, but you need what is clearly a question to begin with.

Comment: I've tried to re-formulate it...

Answer (score 1):

So, here is the whole set-up in GPM:

- `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates`

  - `System/Group Policy`

    - `Configure wireless policy processing`

      - `Allow processing across a slow network connection`: **Enabled**
      - `Do not apply during periodic background processing`: **Disabled**
      - `Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed`: **Disabled**
    - `Specify startup policy processing wait time`: **15** (seconds)
  - `System/Logon` -> `Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon`: **Enabled**
  - `System` -> `Display highly detailed status messages`: **Enabled**

That 15 seconds is an arbitrary number, experimental - depends on how fast and brisk laptops you've got in your Active Directory environment.

This set-up has got some pros and cons, of course:

PROS

➕ Reliable, resilient to abrupt reboots/shutdowns while installing SW in asynchronous (default) mode.

➕ Works on strangely behaving slow Wi-Fi adapters, too.

➕ Users are able to see what is actually happening before logon (and not just seeing annoying rotating wheel)

CONS

➖ Consumes some extra user's time waiting:

- Every new software deployment (everything is synchronous now, before login) once and then - this is a minor issue if you are deploying software occasionally.
- Every (re)boot outside of your company's network (15 seconds timeout) - yeah, now we have to wait the full timeout, because DC is not available (unless you've got public AD set-up)...
- Some laptops need one step extra: to be on AC power, otherwise, their networking is not initialized within 15 seconds either :( (e.g. quite new Lenovo from 2021 with i5 and SSD)